# Woocommerce Price Not Showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I think this is a weird situation. Usually Woocommerce is a normal plugin, when I install it and Voila Ecommerce ready to use. But, when I install it in my staging server, the price never appear.

I try to debug, I print out all value on $product variable. All information I need is placed in there except "price", but regular price appear. If I put "Sale Price", the price appear, ofcourse 2 prices appear, regular and sale. So the function "$product->get_price_html()" was empty. I have tried to downgrade the Woocommerce version, the result is the same. Unlucky me. You can see it on [dev.skripptek.com/kulkulfarm/shop](http://dev.skripptek.com/kulkulfarm/shop)

One problem more, if I use variations, it couldn't saved.

[product dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHkiA.jpg)

I put sale price at above, and below is null.

I have to googled it, and no one have my problems. It make me stressed and crazy. Is anyone have some problem with me? Please help, it's been 3 days.

Additional information

I already debugged Woocommerce. The "price" is never filled with value when I fill the regular price in DB, but when I fill sale price, the "price" filled automaticly with value.

When I try edit product with quick edit, price is also filled with value but not if I edit directly in edit post. Maybe someone in Automattic can help me with this?

---

## Solved

I update this description, it is solved actually see and expand the comments below. Not sure why it happen, it is just happened in my staging server but in production working fine. Maybe need reinstall the WordPress installation or not compatible with apache version or mysql version.

Comment: Does the price exist in the db? Does it display on the admin side?

Comment: In addition, does the price display while using a default theme? Does it display if you turn off all other plugins? Your variations question seems like it should be a separate question.

Comment: On the [single product page](http://dev.skripptek.com/kulkulfarm/product/moringa/) you see the price is " Price: ___". This never happens with default WooCommerce, so we can assume it is a theme/plugin conflict.

Comment: I'm not yet check the DB. Price don't display on admin side too. that's the problems.

I have tried everything. Use default theme, downgrade the plugin, turn off the plugins. I don't know what miss -__-". but it work normally in my local computer

Comment: Already checked, the value of _price is empty. I think the problems is on save event. On debugging

Comment: I got the same issue. I change every price (_max_variation_regular_prices, _max_variation_regular_price, _min_variation_regular_price, _max_variation_price, _min_variation_price, _regular_price, _price) for the parent post and all the derived variations to 2.49, but Frontpage, Productpage and Admin page still show an old price: 3.99. I can't find the value "3.99" inside post_meta. But the moment I edit and save the product the price should 2.49. So I guess it's some save and/or cache issue. Very weird and very disturbing.

Comment: Actually, when I move to another server it work well. I'm not sure why it happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue. It's been working fine with the current child theme (Dazzling) until towards the end of last year.

Products with variants however are behaving correctly. It's the simple product.. if I enter a new product and regular price, it doesn't show "add to cart" and on the previous multiple product listing screen it shows as "read more". If I put a sale price in, it works.

Also, If I remove/clear the sale price that was saved previously and save again, it still has the price I cleared. It's as if wordpress/woocommerce isn't updating the product on this section. All other areas, updating seems fine.

I did a temporary workaround, until this is resolved, by adding a sale price and scheduling it in the past.

I'm seeing a few posts about this issue and starting to suspect it an woocommerce/wordpress issue after an update? I can't be certain though.